# How to put a view over an existing layout with the same effect of a dialog

Tags: android-layout, android

I want to put a a few tutorial text boxes over our existing layout for new users.. I want to create the exact same effect of a dialog; pop up the box, having it point to something and darken everything else..

Someone suggested to use frame layout then put a full screen translucent linear layout over the base layout, but i have no idea how to do that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who's curious, I had to use a non-dialog because the screens were very customized..

Regardless what i did was put my initial layout in a frame layout, then put another layout on top of it (simply by adding another layout under framelayout) that used a translucent background image, then i added my other layouts.. Then in the code (after the inital layout was created), i used various methods on the view i wanted to overlay (getLocationOnScreen() and getLayoutParams() to set the width and height)

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice example in your ApiDemos folder, which creates an activity that looks like a popup dialog.

Here is the [source code](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/DialogActivity.html), and the corresponding [XML layout file](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/res/layout/dialog_activity.html).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a Dialog and call `setContentView`?

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogView);
// initialize the components
```

What do you need to do that you can't do without a dialog?

Comment: that's what i tried initially but the problem was that my layout has curved edges and no matter what it did, around the dialog there was a black border..

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use `Dialog` for this?

Disable (or just don't add) buttons, then add a custom view to the dialog using the `AlertDialog.Builder.setView(View yourView)`:

```
private static final int YOUR_POPUP_ID = 0;

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    if (id == YOUR_POPUP_ID) {
        // yourView is what you actually want to show in popup
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("a title")
            .setView(yourView)
            .create();
    }
}

..

// some where in your code show the popup
showDialog(YOUR_POPUP_ID);
```

Comment: that's what i tried initially but the problem was that my layout has curved edges and no matter what it did, around the dialog there was a black border..