# How to keep a view above a bottomsheet/dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, bottom-sheet

I'm basically trying to implement a custom notification/toast system in my app with a different behavior than a native toast (that's why I'm not using a custom native toast). The way I want to do it is that I want this view to show above of any view (like toast) but I don't know how to keep this view above bottomsheets or dialogs. So far I have this view in the main activity xml but it won't keep the view above bottomsheet or dialog. Any suggestions??

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>                                            
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"           
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"                           
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"                                
    android:layout_width="match_parent"                                           
    android:layout_height="match_parent"                                          
    tools:context=".app.presentation.main_activity.MainActivity">                 
                                                                                  
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView                                  
        android:id="@+id/container"                                               
        android:layout_width="match_parent"                                       
        android:layout_height="match_parent"                                      
        tools:context=".app.presentation.main_activity.MainActivity" />           
                                                                                  
    <com.example.notification.NotificationView                                    
        android:id="@+id/notification_view"                                       
        android:layout_width="match_parent"                                       
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />                                   
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743946/view-above-dialog

Comment: marked solution in that post does not solve my problem

Comment: See this then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159692/how-to-put-a-view-over-an-existing-layout-with-the-same-effect-of-a-dialog

Comment: thanks @cmak but that solution is what I'm already doing and the if I open a dialog it will be above the notification view

Comment: See the answer marked as solution, use views instead of dialogs

Comment: @cmak that question and that solution don't match my question. The OP is trying to create a dialog with a FrameLayout, I'm trying to show a view that will be always above of dialogs

Comment: The only way i can think is to replace all dialogs with view layouts all inside the same root layout, otherwise i don't see how would you be able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `BaseActivity` or `BaseFragment` that initially have the method for you custom notification dialogue and then you can implement the method by implementing `BaseActivity` or `BaseFragment` in your Activity or Fragment.

Below is the example of the same which you can use to perform the same. Here i mentioned my layout in case you have to change your `FrameLayout` which you had mentioned in the question to reflect it. I also managed `ImageView` to render as a progress bar which you can change as per your need.

By using this you don't need to declare the implementation of the function every place you can directly call the function by implementing the Base class.

```
private var progressDialog : Dialog? = null

// To show the custom layout
fun showNotification() {
    if (progressDialog == null) {
        progressDialog = Dialog(requireContext())
    } else {
        return
    }
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(requireContext()).inflate(R.layout.app_loading_dialog, null, false)
    val imageView1 = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView2)
    val a1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(requireContext(), R.anim.progress_anim)
    a1.duration = 1500
    imageView1.startAnimation(a1)

    progressDialog?.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    progressDialog?.setContentView(view)
    val window = progressDialog?.window
    window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), android.R.color.transparent))
    progressDialog?.setCancelable(false)
    progressDialog?.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
    progressDialog?.show()
}

// To hide the custom layout
fun hideLoading() {
    if (progressDialog != null) {
        progressDialog?.dismiss()
        progressDialog = null
    }
}
```

After creating the function you can directly call this function to show the custom layout as a dialogue in your `Fragment` or `Activity`.

I hope this is what you are looking for as per my understanding. Let me know if there is any other clearance needed or i am wrong to understand you.

Comment: This solution will create a dialog on top wich will create an overlay in the rest on the app and it will show the view in the center of the screen, enven so, it can be covered by other dialog wich is what I'm trying to avoid